# How to force a pull to a file in git?

Tags: git, github

I am having a merge conflict, and I can usually just rename the file and pull from the repo ti resolve or manually edit the edit. This time, I committed changes to a file that has conflicts, and it is in the staging area.
I tried using `git reset HEAD <file>`and then using `git pull` again, but I still get merge conflicts.
Is there a way to force the overwrite of the troublesome file?

Here is the message that I get:
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    db/profile_edit.php

I change the name of the file to profile_edit.phpbkup.
Then I do a `git pull`
And I still get the same error. Why is this? The file doesn't even exist anymore, so how can it be replaced?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you not want to keep the changes you committed?  or do you want to merge the two together?

Comment: How do I open up the differences between the two files? Sure, I'd like to do that.

Comment: @egidra: You pull, and let it get the conflicts, and resolve them. See the manpage for git-merge, specifically the "[how conflicts are presented](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_how_conflicts_are_presented)" and "[how to resolve conflicts](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_how_to_resolve_conflicts)" sections.

Comment: From your question and comments, it really sounds like you might want to find a Git tutorial and read through it, too.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to throw away all changes you made concurrently to upstream:

```
git fetch origin
git push -f . origin/branchA:branchA
```

if you want to resolve conflicts favouring upstream instead:

```
git fetch origin
git merge -s recursive -Xtheirs origin/branchA
```

hope this helps.

Comment: what do I do if I am not using branches? We are all on origin.

Comment: I don't suggest working headless. If you are pushing and pulling, you are using branches. You /can/ use tags, but this is not the way to use git properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file out of the index with `git reset filename`, if you don't want those changes add the `--hard` switch to the reset.

The conflicts themselves will need to be resolved.

One option is to `git fetch remoteRepo`
This will fetch the remote repo, but does not try and merge the branches together.

To diff the two versions of the file you are interested in, use `git diff HEAD remoteRepo/remoteBranch <fileName>`

If there are merge conflicts and you want to keep content from both files, there is nothing you can do but resolve the conflicts.

Comment: I still get this error: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: edit.php. I did the reset, then I renamed the file edit.phpbkup, and when I do a "git pull" then I still get the error.

Comment: try using `git stash` before you do the merge